# Use long date format for some items, but only year for other items

Tags: biblatex

Using biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago

In the bibliography: For articles and books, only year should be shown. But for newspaper and magazine articles the full date is relevant.
I have items in my .bib-file (articles and books) with a full date and would prefer not to change this as it is exported from bibliography manager and so on.

So I cannot use the date=year option to biblatex.

My biblatex-chicago options:

```
\usepackage[%
    notes,
    short,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    url=false,
    autolang=hyphen,
    backend=biber,
    abbreviate=true,
    urldate=short
]{biblatex-chicago}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I messed around a bit myself, and it can be solved with:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {\clearfield{month}\clearfield{day}}
    {}}
```

and so on for the other types.

I'm sure it could be done the other way around: specifying types to keep the month and day fields for, but this is good enough for now.

Comment: I have this problem as well. A more permanent solution in biblatex would be welcome